# ipv6 in Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: ios, websocket, dns, ipv6

Apple rejected app update, because it doesn't work with ipv6 connection.
App connects to server over websocket (socket.io, NodeJS, Express). App uses subdomain address to connect to server.

I've set up a Google Load Balancer with two "frontends". One is regular ipv4, another one is ipv6.

I can reach server using load balancer's ipv4 address directly, so i assume this means i've done it correctly.

Load balancer's external reserved ipv6 address looks like that:

`[9999:9999:0:9999::]:80`

I've added "AAAA" DNS record to subdomain. After accepting this address, DNS editor shows it like that:

`9999:9999:0000:9999:0000:0000:0000:0000`

Services like this one: http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php
Are showing these results: http://prntscr.com/i8fk9j

I've created hotspot as described [here by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) (Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly) and connected iphone to this hotspot.
App can't connect to server.
I've also tried to reach healthcheck in Safari address while on the same phone with the same connection. It returns correct response "true", but this has nothing to do with websocket - it's simple REST listener.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It may be nothing to do with IPv6. Apple is simply telling you that the app had an issue and they tested in on an IPv6 environment, in case that has an impact.  You need to look at the symptoms they described and determine what the actual issue is.

Comment: app clearly shows that it can't reach server. No doubt about that: they've provided screenshot where app shows "Cannot reach server" message when they are attempting to log in. And also they are explicitly saying that this problem shows up only when they are using ipv6.

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: How about that red cross on your IPv6 test report then?  You have no IPv6 accessible DNS servers, so perhaps they cannot resolve the host on a pure IPv6 network.

Comment: @Paulw11 red cross? Are you saying i can just declare that app doesn't work on ipv6 networks? I can't find such option, could you point at it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton if you are referring to apple's screenshot, then it shows nothing but user interface of SignIn scene and our custom snackbar message "Can't reach server".

Comment: @stkvtflw In your IPv6 test screenshot https://prnt.sc/i8fk9j , the last test failed; Your domain has no IPv6 DNS servers; it only has IPv4 DNS servers.  It states that this may prevent access from some IPv6 only networks.

Comment: @Paulw11 okay, it makes sense. What do i suppose to do about it?

Comment: Find a DNS host that has IPv6 connected DNS servers?

Comment: it's Dreamhost. How do i know if they have it?